# In VS Code with Python how do I make the first parameter (self) in class methods italics?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using Python I came from Pycharm where it automatically formatted the first parameter (often self) in class methods to be in italics which I found easier to review when going through my code.  Can you configure VS Code settings to do this?  I see there is the following and I played with it adding function color but couldnt get the ability to just make the first parameter of class methods be in italics for Python.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes

Thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are able to do this by editing the `settings.json` file. To open this file and get to the settings, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and enter **Open Settings (JSON)** from within VS code. Then, you'll want to add the following keys and values at the top level:

**Edit**: I had forgotten the `"textMateRules"` key which is why you were having trouble seeing the changes. I also commented out everything except `"variable.parameter.function.language.special.self.python"` since you mentioned that's all you want modified.

```
{
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": [
                    //"variable.language.special.self.python",
                    "variable.parameter.function.language.special.self.python",
                    //"variable.language.special.cls.python",
                    //"variable.parameter.function.language.special.cls.python"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "fontStyle": "italic"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What you're doing here is telling the syntax highlighter to take the `self` and `cls` keywords (everything within the `"scope"` list) and apply an italic style to them.

The `"scope"` list is (in English):

1. `"variable.language.special.self.python"`: The keyword `self` that is *not* part of a function definition argument list.
2. `"variable.parameter.function.language.special.self.python"`: The keyword `self` when it is used as part of a function definition argument list.
3. `"variable.language.special.cls.python"`: Same as (1) but with `cls`.
4. `"variable.parameter.function.language.special.cls.python"`: Same as (2) but with `cls`.

This changes their appearance *everywhere* which may or may not be what you want. For example, these changes give me (along with my current theme) the following look:

[image: italic self and cls]

You should be able to enter any combination of values (separated by a space) in place of `italic`. For instance, you can enter `bold underline` if you want `self` and `cls` to be bolded and underlined instead.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation.  So if I only want it to be for python, with self, and part of function definitions then I should have scope with only "variable.parameter.function.language.special.self.python"?

Comment: I've also implemented that exact settings.json and restarted my vs code but continue to see the old formatting.  Is there something else to enable it?

Comment: Does the file you're looking in end with `.py`? I believe syntax highlighting depends on the file extension. I'll take another look at my VScode JSON tomorrow and update you if I find anything

Comment: Yes, I tried multiple and they are all py files. Thanks!