# Python syntax in vscode

Tags: python, function, class

Hello I’m a newbie programmer self-learning python and I just got to the classes and object chapter. I couldn’t help but notice that in my tutorials when creating a function or method in a class it automatically passes this (self) to the function but my vscode editor doesn’t.
Is it possible that it’s because I’m running an Ubuntu O.S

I was trying to define this simple class with some functions according to my tutorial instructions.

```py
Class details:
    Def info(self):
```

But I was getting this instead

```py
Class details:
    Def info():
```

you’d notice like I said above my editor doesn’t add this ‘self’ to my function.
Should I be worried???

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you define a method for a class, `self` should be the first parameter in a method definition, since it will be automatically passed by python. If you want to VS Code to automatically add it check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60498785/14536215). Ps. `class` and `def` should be lower case :)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with typing `self` yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add custom code snippets in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995863/how-to-add-custom-code-snippets-in-vscode) (What you're looking at is snippets, VS Code used to have snippets builtin to the Python extension but doesn't anymore, you can add your own if you want)

Answer (score 1):

First, you should make sure that you write the keywords `def` and `class` in lower case.

Furthermore you have to install the Python Extension in VSCode to use Code completion. AFAIK the `self` keyword is not added automatically by VSCode. You have to add it yourself. This is independent from your Host OS. This applies to Python 3.x.

May you have to change your Python version in VSCode.